# ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta 1 Block Access to Razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to block access (404) to the Razor views in MVC 3 beta 1? When I create a brand new blank site (IIS7) and then access /views/home/index.cshtml from the browser, instead of the 404 I get this

```
    [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.Index_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.]
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, VirtualPathFactoryManager virtualPathFactoryManager) +56
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +253
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +89
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

By default the web.config file in the views folder is set to block all file requests, but obviously this request is still getting through.

**Steps to reproduce:** 

File -> New Project 
ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application 
Internet Application (Razor) 
F5
Navigate to /views/home/index.cshtml

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Updated with full stack trace and steps to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this is a valid bug.

Comment: What happen if you ignore the route in the global.asax?
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.cshtml/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: I already tried so but nothing changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm a dev lead on the ASP.NET team working on both ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET Web Pages and Razor.

This is not entirely fixed in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC, but it will be fully fixed in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM.

There is nothing "terribly bad" that happens in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC or earlier: The worst that can happen is that someone can detect whether a view exists in your app - but they *cannot* get it to run (due to that weird exception). This is a slight security issue in that it is a form of information disclosure, but it is not a very severe issue.

In ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM all Razor views in ~/Views/... as well as any Razor views within an MVC Area are 100% blocked and will not be directly runnable by the browser. They will only be runnable as MVC view pages.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use some kind of rewrite rules in web.config to redirect the user from the directly linked .cshtml to the actual action or just redirect/rewrite it to a 404 page.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*.cshtml" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/some404.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Update: A more complex version. This will take a URL like `views/home/index.cshtml?key=value` and redirect it to `home/index?key=value`. It's a 301 redirect, but it can also be a Rewrite or some other http status code - [more here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/468/using-global-and-distributed-rewrite-rules/)

```
<rule name="cshtml" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^views/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.(?:cshtml|aspx)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Of course this works without the query string (the `?key=value` part). The only drawback of this is that web.config does not know about your registered routes (usually in Global.asax.cs). And, to my knowledge, there is now way it could. For that you'll have to write some custom code. Look at [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) by Phil Haack and the source code that goes with it.

Comment: That does not solve the problem – I don't want to ignore these or display 404 error pages but display them ...

Answer (score 3):

For those migrated from MVC3 RC into RTM, make sure you look into the \views\web.config, and add the following config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

This is will make sure all the view files (*.cshtml) return 404 not found.